# Should there be made a seperate tag for the Steam app?

Tags: discussion, tags

Some user asked [a question about having a problem with the mobile Steam app](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/344747/222753). It was tagged with [steam](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam). I thought that it would be best if it was tagged with a tag specific for the app, but I could not find one.

Shouldn't there be made a seperate tag for the Steam app?

I suggest [steam-app](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam-app).

Comment: I think perhaps [steam-mobile] would make more sense and be more clear

Answer (score 1):

I see the [steam-mobile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam-mobile) tag has been added to the question. It was done by moderator [Robotnik](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/28182/robotnik). So I guess that's a **yes**.

Comment: I should probably learn to check meta first :)